# Update hashset from .txt while app is running

Tags: java, spring

The goal is to block access to the page from the list of IP addresses. This list is in the file list.txt.
I made the service that checks IP from request and with HashSet of "unwanted" addresses, but subgoal is "catch on the fly" this list.txt. What I mean: if I add some IP to this file, it should be blocked without restarting application. And I have not ideas how to solve this, cause my app refreshes this list only after restart. My code is below

```
    @Service
public class BlackListService {

    public Set<String> loadBlackList() {
        java.util.Set<java.lang.String> blackList = new HashSet<>();
        InputStream resource = null;
        try {
            resource = new ClassPathResource(
                    "blacklist.txt").getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource))) {
            blackList = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.toSet());
            for (java.lang.String address:
                    blackList) {
                System.out.println(address);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return blackList;
    }

    public boolean isNowAllowedIP(Set<String> blackList, String requestIP) {
        return blackList.contains(requestIP);
    }

}
```

And controller:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    private final BlackListService blackListService;

    public MainController(BlackListService blackListService) {
        this.blackListService = blackListService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String mainPage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        Set<String> blackList = blackListService.loadBlackList();

        if (blackListService.isNowAllowedIP(blackList, request.getRemoteAddr())) {
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Access logs");
            logger.warning("Access disallowed");
            model.addAttribute("message", request.getRemoteAddr() + ": Access disallowed");
            return "index";
        }
        model.addAttribute("message", "Access allowed");
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Can someone help with this "subgoal"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In loadBlackList() you are reading a resource from the classpath. Could this be picking up a file built into your jar file or build dir which is not the file you are editing? I would try changing loadBlackList() to use FileReader and a path on the file system rather than a path within the classpath instead of InputStreamReader.

Comment: I did so in the end. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a recurring background job that will reload your blacklist after you change it. This [blog](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/job-scheduler-example/) will discusses a "modern" approach for doing it with Spring.

- Save the last modified time for the file when your program starts and you first load it. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getLastModifiedTime-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-) for checking the file modified time.
- Schedule the background job to run every minute (or 5 or whatever is frequent enough for your needs).
- When the job runs check the current last updated time on the file and if its different than the saved one, then its time to reload your list.

Comment: I'm trying to load file every time when I call GET request in Set<String> blackList = blackListService.loadBlackList();
Will the Scheduling help me? Im not sure to be honest. Or mb i dont understand how Scheduling works...

Comment: OK, I see the reload line in your mainPage now. No scheduling wouldn't help unless there's another controller where you needed the blacklist and it was cached instead of recreating it every time.